# Ruby delete method (string manipulation)

Tags: ruby, string, delete-method

I'm new to Ruby, and have been working my way through Mr Neighborly's Humble Little Ruby Guide. There have been a few typos in the code examples along the way, but I've always managed to work out what's wrong and subsequently fix it - until now!

This is really basic, but I can't get the following example to work on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard):

```
gone = "Got gone fool!"
puts "Original: " + gone
gone.delete!("o", "r-v")
puts "deleted: " + gone
```

Output I'm expecting is:

```
Original: Got gone fool!
deleted: G gne fl!
```

Output I actually get is:

```
Original: Got gone fool!
deleted: Got gone fool!
```

The delete! method doesn't seem to have had any effect.

Can anyone shed any light on what's going wrong here? :-\

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `String.delete` method ([Documented here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000832)) treats its arguments as arrays and then deletes characters based upon the *intersection* of its arrays.

The intersection of 2 arrays is all characters that are common to both arrays. So your original delete of `gone.delete!("o", "r-v")` would become

```
gone.delete ['o'] & ['r','s','t','u','v']
```

There are no characters present in both arrays so the deletion would get an empty array, hence no characters are deleted.

Comment: Another typo chalked up to the examples in the book then. ;-)
Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I changed

```
gone.delete!("o", "r-v")
```

to

```
gone.delete!("or-v")
```

and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried just about everything but that! Out of interest, are you on MAC OS X, too?

Comment: Nope. I use ruby on windows and linux. Most of ruby should be OS agnostic and so any initial problems you face shouldn't be specific to OS X.

Comment: Careful about expansion when using double quotes : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4190812/1729094

Answer (score 1):

You get same o/p using some different way like [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817)

```
puts "deleted: " + gone.gsub('o', '')
```

o/p

```
deleted: Got gone fool!
```

Comment: Strange, isn't it? Are you on MAC OS X, too?