# How can I remove the string "\n" from within a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

```
"some text\nandsomemore"
```

I need to remove the "\n" from it. I've tried

```
"some text\nandsomemore".gsub('\n','')
```

but it doesn't work. How do I do it? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You need to use `"\n"` not `'\n'` in your gsub. The different quote marks behave differently.

Double quotes `"` allow character expansion and expression interpolation ie. they let you use escaped control chars like `\n` to represent their true value, in this case, *newline*, and allow the use of `#{expression}` so you can weave variables and, well, pretty much any ruby expression you like into the text.

While on the other hand, single quotes `'` treat the string literally, so there's no expansion, replacement, interpolation or what have you.

In this particular case, it's better to use either the `.delete` or `.tr` String method to delete the *newlines*.

[See here for more info](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Strings)

Comment: proper syntax would really be .gsub(/\n/, "")

Comment: @David is correct. However, I felt that it was important to show that the quotes make a difference, since that would benefit Ben at this point. Mind you, David, it's probably more of a matter of style than "correct". Personally I think `tr` is a better choice for this task, but as I say, I thought it better to point out the difference in single, double quotes when I answered.

Comment: why is it better to use `.delete` or `.tr` ?

Comment: They're faster than `.gsub` because they do less (`.delete` would very likely be fastest, although a performance profiling would be good to 100% confirm this.)

Answer (score 86):

If you want or don't mind having all the leading and trailing whitespace from your string removed you can use the `strip` method.

```
"    hello    ".strip   #=> "hello"   
"\tgoodbye\r\n".strip   #=> "goodbye"
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7095275/211292).

**edit** The original title for this question was different. My answer is for the original question.

Comment: This does not answer the question. `strip` only removes leading and trailing whitespace: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip-21

Comment: @mvdanj Yes, given the details of this particular question it doesn't answer it, but it does answer the question just based on the title. I suspect that is why people have found it useful.

Comment: The title was changed from the time when I originally answered.

Answer (score 65):

When you want to remove a string, rather than replace it you can use `String#delete` (or its mutator equivalent `String#delete!`), e.g.:

```
x = "foo\nfoo"
x.delete!("\n")
```

`x` now equals "foofoo"

In this specific case `String#delete` is more readable than `gsub` since you are not actually replacing the string with anything.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9.3 at least, `delete` is not destructive as indicated here. It returns a new string.

Comment: Well spotted. I've updated that code snippet to use the mutator version String#delete! rather than String#delete

Answer (score 33):

You don't need a regex for this. Use tr:

```
"some text\nandsomemore".tr("\n","")
```

Comment: what is the difference between tr an replace?

Comment: `replace` just changes the string to a new one, like variable assignment; whereas `tr` is a character-by-character global find and replace.

Comment: and the difference with gsub?

Answer (score 19):

use `chomp` or `strip` functions from Ruby:

```
"abcd\n".chomp => "abcd"
"abcd\n".strip => "abcd"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. `strip` only removes leading and trailing whitespace - http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip-21

Comment: in chomp method, \n and \r are removed from the end of str if they exist, not in the middle. So this doesn't solve OP question

Answer (score 1):

for some reason none of those answer works in my case, I figured out my own solution:

```
3.1.2 :003 > "some text\nandsomemore".split.join(' ')
 => "some text andsomemore"
```

Comment: This returns `sometextandsomemore`, so not at all what is being asked here.

Comment: @josemigallas my mistake, you should use a delimiter when join, the answer has been updated

Answer (score 0):

`#squish` will remove all spacing including newlines and tabs.

```rb
"some text\nandsomemore".squish #=> "some textandsomemore"

"some      text\nand\n\n\n\n\some   \t\tmore".squish #=> "some textandsomemore"
```