# Ruby fails to detect newline character in a string

Tags: ruby, string, newline

I have the following string and I want to detect the newline character there. But the Ruby's string method `include?` fails to detect it.

I am running `Ruby 1.9.2p290`. Where am I going wrong there?

```
"/'ædres/ \nYour ".include?('\n')
 => false
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the string "\n" from a Ruby string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190797/how-can-i-remove-the-string-n-from-a-ruby-string)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`\n` needs to be in a double quoted string, otherwise there'll be no escaping.

```
>> "\n".include? '\n'
=> false
>> "\n".include? "\n"
=> true
```