# Ruby Filter gsub replace \\n

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I want to replace '\\n' with '\n'

i am using the gsub method but cannot replace

```
ruby
{

code => "@mystring=event.get('stockLines');
@mystring=@mystring.gsub('\\\n', '\n');"

}
```

Comment: I don't see why the three tags other than "ruby" are there. If they are not relevent--I don't see why they would be--they should not be included. Tags are to assist in searches. If a member wants to examine questions concerning, say, `logstash`, would they want to see this question?

Answer (score 1):

> You need to use "\n" not '\n' in your gsub. The different quote marks behave differently.

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190797/how-can-i-remove-the-string-n-from-within-a-ruby-string)

In your case:

```
@mystring.gsub("\\n", "\n")
```

The essential difference between the two literal forms of strings (single or double quotes) is that double quotes allow for escape sequences while single quotes do not!

Answer (score -2):

Escaping of the backslash can be a bit weird.

For a regular Ruby script the code would be:

```
@mystring = event.get('stockLines').gsub('\\\\\n', '\n')
```

It seems like in logstash config the code is also in a string, so it needs to be escaped once more, i.e.:

```
ruby
{
code => "@mystring = event.get('stockLines').gsub('\\\\\\\\\\n', '\\n');"
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't replace. Are you sure you meant gsub!. not gsub.

Comment: `gsub!` replaces in-place. `@mystring.gsub!(...);` is the same as doing `@mystring = @mystring.gsub(...);`.

Comment: I tried by both, it doesn't replace. I get the same \\n in the string.

Comment: `ruby -e "foo = '\\\\\n'; puts foo; puts foo.gsub('\\\\\n', '\n')"` -- works for me.

Comment: I'm writing in the logstash script as mentioned in the question. It is not working there.

Comment: Well, the string wasn't sufficiently escaped. It is likely that string in the `code =>` also needs to be escaped once more. I told you what the issue is -- make some effort and work out the solution that works for you from here.