# How to split text on two new lines with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my RoR application, I have a text area and would like to split its content into separate paragraphs. The text has the following format:

```
Berlin.
Rome.
London.

Paris.
Warsaw.
New York City.
```

When displayed, I would like to have it formatted in paragraphs like:

```
<p>Berlin. Rome. London.</p>
<p>Paris. Warsaw. New York City.</p>
```

How to achieve that? I suppose I need to use split method but how to target two new lines?

Comment: You might want to have a look at Rails' [`simple_format`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper.

Answer (score 9):

When you split the text field value with `text.split("\n\n")` you will get split value in an array i.e output be like 
`["Berlin.\nRome.\nLondon.", "Paris.\nWarsaw.\nNew York City."]` .To print value in following way

```
'<p>Berlin. Rome. London.</p>
<p>Paris. Warsaw. New York City.</p>'
```

need to remove `"\n"` from array elements and add `" "` by using gsub ruby method.

```
<% text.split("\n\n").each do |paragraph| %>
 <p>
    <%= paragraph.gsub("\n"," ") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

you may also refer [How can I remove the string "\n" from within a Ruby string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190797/how-can-i-remove-the-string-n-from-within-a-ruby-string)

Comment: This seems to be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it on double newline and then wrap in `<p>` in the view (ERB example)

```
<% text.split("\n\n").each do |paragraph| %>
  <p>
    <%= paragraph %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you but your code for some reason displays text in one paragraph, not two.

Comment: Try now, I've fixed the pattern from `'\n\n'` to `"\n\n"` to match newline chars, not backslash `n`.

Comment: Sorry, I still see only one paragraph. Maybe it is something do do with my Ruby or RoR version?

Comment: Try to take this data in the console and print it there with `p text` (it will show all the special chars). Also print the result of `text.split("\n\n")`

Comment: I have it .split("\r\n\r\n") Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use `.split("#{$/}#{/$}")` for this to get the newline character for your system.